# Unable to 'index type' using a string variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to invert an object's fields if a value exists, but I'm getting some error that I cannot decipher.

```
interface Control {
  name1: boolean;
  name2: boolean;
  ...
}

const values = ['name1', 'name2', ...];

const control: Control = {
  name1: false,
  name2: false,
  ...
}

for (const value of values) {
  if ((value in control) {
    control[value] = !control[value];  // error
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Control'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Control'.ts(7053)
```

However, the error goes away if I explicitly pass one of the object's fields, such as `control['name1']`.
Is there something I am not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know that your `values` array is an array of specific strings, only that it's a `string[]`. Try this:

```
interface Control {
  name1: boolean;
  name2: boolean;
}

const values = ['name1', 'name2'] as const;

const control: Control = {
  name1: false,
  name2: false,
}

for (const value of values) {
  if (value in control) {
    control[value] = !control[value];  // error
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtxXQG2QbwChlkQ4BbCARgC5kAjdXCOEAbmNIogCY7HmrDgF9ChBJgDOYZADc4OAK4RJyALzIA2gHIylKtoA0yXdx7aAusjiqJIaR3FSZdsNhx0MWXOoKc91HTwOJIQhv5mQQqh4aKEMOhQyAAUdtJyCsrI6DAZSioAlH4kwLnJ8vnIoMiu7kVEJCS1uJoVylYaAITNOK2ZEBZsJAD0w8jQ2FCcosJAA)

That `as const` tells TypeScript to specify the type of `values` more tightly to be `['name1', 'name2']` in this case, so when you're iterating through it `value` will be typed as `'name1' | 'name2'` and TypeScript will understand that those values can be used to index a `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` variable can be any value during application runtime and TypeScript has no awareness that it is a valid key defined within the `control` object. Hence it cannot simply infer the value type of `control[value]`.

The fix is however very simple, all that needs to be done is to tell TypeScript that the `values` array only contains valid keys from the `Control` type via the use of the `keyof Control` syntax:

```
const values: (keyof Control)[] = ['name1', 'name2'];
```

Here is a link to the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtxXQG2QbwChlkQ4BbCARgC5kAjdXCOEAbmNIogCY7HmrDgF9ChBJgDOYZADc4OAK4RJdABQBrCAE90MNJjDYcASgDaAXWQBeZGYDkZSlXsAaZI%20497FjuKkyEli4dBjBeLZEJE7UdPA4khCunDF8yPGJyaKEMOhQyGpB0nIKysh6JUoqJgScwPpq8lXIoMhBRrg1USRthsZmTcpWtgCE7f2DEL6cosJAA).